# Trouble with copying dictionaries and using deepcopy on an SQLAlchemy ORM object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, deep-copy, simulated-annealing

I'm doing a Simulated Annealing algorithm to optimise a given allocation of students and projects.

This is language-agnostic pseudocode from Wikipedia:

```
s ← s0; e ← E(s)                                // Initial state, energy.
sbest ← s; ebest ← e                            // Initial "best" solution
k ← 0                                           // Energy evaluation count.
while k < kmax and e > emax                     // While time left & not good enough:
  snew ← neighbour(s)                           // Pick some neighbour.
  enew ← E(snew)                                // Compute its energy.
  if enew < ebest then                          // Is this a new best?
    sbest ← snew; ebest ← enew                  // Save 'new neighbour' to 'best found'.
  if P(e, enew, temp(k/kmax)) > random() then   // Should we move to it?
    s ← snew; e ← enew                          // Yes, change state.
  k ← k + 1                                     // One more evaluation done
return sbest                                    // Return the best solution found.
```

The following is an adaptation of the technique. My supervisor said the idea is fine in theory.

First I pick up some allocation (i.e. an entire dictionary of students and their allocated projects, including the ranks for the projects) from entire set of randomised allocations, copy it and pass it to my function. Let's call this allocation `aOld` (it is a dictionary). `aOld` has a weight related to it called `wOld`. The weighting is described below.

The function does the following:

- Let this allocation, `aOld` be the `best_node`
- From all the students, pick a random number of students and stick in a list
- Strip (DEALLOCATE) them of their projects ++ reflect the changes for projects (`allocated` parameter is now `False`) and lecturers (free up slots if one or more of their projects are no longer allocated)
- Randomise that list
- Try assigning (REALLOCATE) everyone in that list projects again
- Calculate the weight (add up ranks, rank 1 = 1, rank 2 = 2... and no project rank = 101)
- For this new allocation `aNew`, if the weight `wNew` is smaller than the allocation weight `wOld` I picked up at the beginning, then this is the `best_node` (as defined by the `Simulated Annealing` algorithm above). Apply the algorithm  to `aNew` and continue.
- If `wOld < wNew`, then apply the algorithm to `aOld` again and continue.

The allocations/data-points are expressed as "nodes" such that a `node = (weight, allocation_dict, projects_dict, lecturers_dict)`

Right now, I can only perform this algorithm once, but I'll need to try for a number N (denoted by `kmax` in the Wikipedia snippet) and make sure I always have with me, the previous `node` and the `best_node`.

So that I don't modify my original dictionaries (which I might want to reset to), I've done a shallow copy of the dictionaries. From what I've read in the docs, it seems that it only copies the references and since my dictionaries contain objects, changing the copied dictionary ends up changing the objects anyway. So I tried to use `copy.deepcopy()`.These dictionaries refer to objects that have been mapped with SQLA.

---

`Questions:`

I've been given some solutions to the problems faced but due to my über green-ness with using Python, they all sound rather cryptic to me.

1. Deepcopy isn't playing nicely with SQLA. I've been told thatdeepcopy on ORM objects probably has issues that prevent it from working as you'd expect. Apparently I'd be better off "building copy constructors, i.e. def copy(self):  return FooBar(....)." *Can someone please explain what that means?*
2. I checked and found out that `deepcopy` has issues because SQLAlchemy places extra information on your objects, i.e. an `_sa_instance_state` attribute, that I wouldn't want in the copy but is necessary for the object to have. I've been told: "There are ways to manually blow away the old `_sa_instance_state` and put a new one on the object, but the most straightforward is to make a new object with `__init__()` and set up the attributes that are significant, instead of doing a full deep copy." *What exactly does that mean? Do I create a new, unmapped class similar to the old, mapped one?*
3. An alternate solution is that I'd have to "implement `__deepcopy__()` on your objects and ensure that a new _sa_instance_state is set up, there are functions in sqlalchemy.orm.attributes which can help with that." *Once again this is beyond me so could someone kindly explain what it means?*
4. A more general question: given the above information are there any suggestions on how I can maintain the information/state for the `best_node` (which must always persist through my while loop) and the `previous_node`, if my actual objects (referenced by the dictionaries, therefore the nodes) are changing due to the deallocation/reallocation taking place? That is, without using copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have another possible solution: use transactions. This probably still isn't the best solution but implementing it should be faster.

Firstly create your session like this:

```
# transactional session
Session = sessionmaker(transactional=True)
sess = Session()
```

That way it will be transactional. The way transactions work is that `sess.commit()` will make your changes permanent while `sess.rollback()` will revert them.

In the case of simulated annealing you want to commit when you find a new best solution. At any later point, you can invoke rollback() to revert the status back to that position.

Comment: This looks interesting. What does `sess.rollback()` revert to? The original or the previous state? Additionally, this means I wouldn't actually have to change any of my Classes would I? Just the point where I commit them changes right?

Comment: sess.rollback() will revert back to the state as of the last call to sess.commit(). Your dictionaries aren't SQLAlchemy objects so they will not be reverted. You'll have to handle those yourself. Other then that, you should not require any additional changes.

Comment: It doesn't significantly change anything but the `rollback()` ability is quite useful since I'm hopping from "state" to "state".

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to copy sqlalchemy objects like that. You could implement your own methods which make the copies easily enough, but that is probably not want you want. You don't want copies of students and projects in your database do you? So don't copy that data.

So you have a dictionary which holds your allocations. During the process you should never modify the SQLAlchemy objects. All information that can be modified should be stored in those dictionaries. If you need to modify the objects to take that into account, copy the data back at the end.

Comment: @Winston: I wish I could implement my own methods to make the copying easier but I'm almost out of time and still quite a beginner at Python programming (and programming in general) so that seems a bit daunting at this time :). Yup, I have a dictionary that holds the allocations -- I only ever add rows to it and then never touch it save for querying information. It's the `student`, `project` and `lecturers` dictionaries that I'm changing for the Simulated Annealing.

Comment: [continued] So far, SQLAlchemy hasn't actually complained although what I'm doing is -- according to responses to my questions -- wrong (changing a mapped object after it's been added to the session). My main issue is that I need to use the concept for `deepcopy` but can't. The reason I mapped `Student`, et al is because I had to keep my Allocation mapping very simple. Thus the student id's in Allocation are foreign keys in to the Student-mapped table (so I can query info about the students when needed). It's a bit crazy :)

Comment: @Winston: Now that you mention it, I just remembered that I have a function called `resetSPL()` that basically resets the attributes of students, projects and lecturers... I should _not_ be doing that should I?

Comment: No, essentially when doing an algorithm like simulated annealing you really shouldn't be using sqlalchemy. SQLAlchemy is for persistence which is not something you want. Your use of it, and its intended use are too different: you are simply going to get headaches.

Comment: The SQLA works nicely for my Monte-Carlo simulation since I keep adding all the stuff to the DB and later use it for calculations -- I guess that's where I need persistence the most. Additionally, I'd like to store all my simulations to the database for later reference... but then I need to need to generate a key that's unique to each simulation run... _sigh_

Comment: " I keep adding all the stuff to the DB and later use it for calculations"

Are you adding stuff to the DB while doing the annealing or beforehand?

Comment: @Winston: For the Monte-Carlo I add instances of an object that are different from either students, supervisors or lecturers. Think of it as the bare minimum needed to express my solution within a database (so an incrementing key, a session_id, relevant student, project id's (purely numerical) and rank). For the annealing: all object manipulations are now done on unmapped objects and passed over to a mapped object so that I can preserve my "best" output :)