# Help with copy and deepcopy in Python

Tags: python, copy, sqlalchemy

I think I tried to ask for far too much in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970456/trouble-with-copying-dictionaries-and-using-deepcopy-on-an-sqlalchemy-orm-object) so apologies for that. Let me lay out my situation in as simple a manner as I can this time.

Basically, I've got a bunch of dictionaries that reference my objects, which are in turn mapped using SQLAlchemy. All fine with me. However, I want to make iterative changes to the contents of those dictionaries. The problem is that doing so will change the objects they reference---and using copy.copy() does no good since it only copies the references contained within the dictionary. Thus even if copied something, when I try to, say `print` the contents of the dictionary, I'll only get the latest updated values for the object.

This is why I wanted to use copy.deepcopy() but that does not work with SQLAlchemy. Now I'm in a dilemma since I need to copy certain attributes of my object before making said iterative changes.

In summary, I need to use SQLAlchemy **and** at the same time make sure I can have a copy of my object attributes when making changes so I don't change the referenced object itself.

Any advice, help, suggestions, etc.?

---

`Edit:` Have added some code.

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, sid, name, allocated_proj_ref, allocated_rank):
        self.sid = sid
        self.name = name
        self.allocated_proj_ref = None
        self.allocated_rank = None

students_table = Table('studs', metadata,
    Column('sid', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String),
    Column('allocated_proj_ref', Integer, ForeignKey('projs.proj_id')),
    Column('allocated_rank', Integer)
)

mapper(Student, students_table, properties={'proj' : relation(Project)})

students = {}

students[sid] = Student(sid, name, allocated_project, allocated_rank)
```

Thus, the attributes that I will be changing are the `allocated_proj_ref` and `allocated_rank` attributes. The `students_table` is keyed using the unique student ID (`sid`).

---

`Question`

I'd want to persist the attributes I change above -- I mean, that's basically why I decided to use SQLA. However, the mapped object will be changing, which is not recommended. Thus, if I make the changes to doppelgänger, **unmapped** object... can I take those changes and update the fields/table for the **mapped** object.

In a sense I'm following David's [secondary solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983275/help-with-copy-and-deepcopy-in-python/2983310#2983310) where I create another version of the Class that isn't mapped.

---

I tried using the `StudentDBRecord` solution mentioned below but got an error!

```
File "Main.py", line 25, in <module>
    prefsTableFile = 'Database/prefs-table.txt')
File "/XXXX/DataReader.py", line 158, in readData
readProjectsFile(projectsFile)
File "/XXXX/DataReader.py", line 66, in readProjectsFile
supervisors[ee_id] = Supervisor(ee_id, name, original_quota, loading_limit)
File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
raise exc.UnmappedClassError(class_)
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedClassError: Class 'ProjectParties.Student' is not mapped
```

Does this mean that `Student` *must* be mapped?

---

`Health warning!`

Someone pointed out a really good additional issue here. See, even if I'm calling `copy.deepcopy()` on a non-mapped object, in this case, let's assume it's the students dictionary I've defined above, deepcopy makes a copy of *everything*. My `allocated_proj_ref` is actually a `Project` object, and I've got a corresponding `projects` dictionary for that.

So I deepcopy both `students` and `projects` -- which I am -- he says I'll have cases where the `students`'s `allocated_proj_ref` attribute will have issues with matching with instances in the `projects` dictionary.

Thus, I take it that I'll have to redefine/override (that's what it's called isn't it?) `deepcopy` in each Class using `def __deecopy__(self, memo):` or something like that?

---

I'd I'd like to override `__deepcopy__` such that it ignores all the SQLA stuff (which are `<class 'sqlalchemy.util.symbol'>` and `<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState'>`) but copy everything else that's part of the a mapped class.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: When you modify the mapped objects, do you want the originals or the changed versions to be persisted?

Comment: @Winston: Either have the originals persist or a specific changed version (`best` - see edits) to persist. I can already see problems with the latter since `best` doesn't stay still since I'm updating the object itself. Sigh.

Comment: In response to your edits: why the heck are you using a database to do this? It would make a lot more sense to have `Student` as a regular Python class, and store it in a database (or file) only _after_ you find the global optimum.

Comment: @David: In order to store it in a database, I still need to map it using SQLA right? Should I then commit the changes to 'Student' after I've found my optimum? (Right now, I commit the students dictionary before I run the program... but then I realised I've got something called `resetSPL()` that actually changes the object attributes. SQLA hasn't actually complained about that, but I know now that I shouldn't be changing it.

Comment: @Az: True, if you're going to store the information in a DB you do need to map _something_ using SQLA (or of course you could use a lower-level DB interface). What I'm suggesting is that you only write to the database once, at the end when you have the final optimum solution. Either configure SQLAlchemy to ignore any changes to your `Student` instances while your optimization is running, or use a regular unmapped version of `Student` for the algorithm and only transfer the data into mapped `Student` objects when you're done.

Comment: @David: I think your last suggestion would probably the easiest to implement. [Edit] Sorry, just noticed the edit to your answer. Looks pretty good (and probably far more elegant than writing out a `class StudentUnmapped()` that's the same! I'd have to write to both classes at the same time then so the code would just be repetitious :)

Comment: @Az: What is `ProjectParties`?

Comment: @David: The module that has all the Classes including `Student`, `Project`... etc as well as the SQLA table layouts and the mapper.

Comment: @Az: See my edits to my answer, then. Or try what Denis suggested, that seems like a good idea. (I'm not familiar enough with SQLAlchemy to have come up with that, although I thought something along those lines might be possible)

Comment: @David: Thanks for the help. Your updated solution is sort of what I've been doing except in reverse. One more thing: as long as I haven't committed my objects to the database, I can change their attributes right? Denis' solution looks interesting but I'm far too inexperienced in SQLA to pull that off :) Also, why is `StudentDBRecord` (new one) still `def __init__(self, student)`? Is there really a difference if I made it `def __init__(self, sid, name...)`? That's where my inexperience with Python comes in.

Comment: @Az: on your last point, there's no reason it has to be `__init__(self, student)` instead of `__init__(self, sid, ...)`. Either way would work. But since you'll only ever be constructing a `StudentDBRecord` as a copy of an existing `Student`, it makes sense to just pass the `Student` to the constructor.

Comment: @David: Gotcha. I'm starting to understand the weird `__`'s of Python a lot better now and I really must thank you for the learning experience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm remembering/thinking correctly, in SQLAlchemy you normally have only one object at a time that corresponds to a given database record. This is done so that SQLAlchemy can keep your Python objects in sync with the database, and vice-versa (well, not if there are concurrent DB mutations from outside Python, but that's another story). So the problem is that, if you were to copy one of these mapped objects, you'd wind up with two distinct objects that correspond to the same database record. If you change one, then they would have different values, and the database can't match both of them at the same time.

I think what you may need to do is decide whether you want the database record to reflect the changes you make when you change an attribute of your copy. If so, then you shouldn't be copying the objects at all, you should just be reusing the same instances.

On the other hand, if you don't want the original database record to change when you update the copy, you have another choice: should the copy become a new row in the database? Or should it not be mapped to a database record at all? In the former case, you can implement the copy operation by creating a new instance of the same class and copying over the values, pretty much the same way you created the original object. This would probably be done in the [`__deepcopy__()`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) method of your SQLAlchemy mapped class. In the latter case (no mapping), you would need a separate class that has all the same fields but is not mapped using SQLAlchemy. Actually, it would probably make more sense to have your SQLAlchemy-mapped class be a subclass of this non-mapped class, and only do the mapping for the subclass.

*EDIT*: OK, to clarify what I meant by that last point: right now you have a `Student` class that's used to represent your students. What I'm suggesting is that you make `Student` an unmapped, regular class:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, sid, name, allocated_proj_ref, allocated_rank):
        self.sid = sid
        self.name = name
        self.allocated_project = None
        self.allocated_rank = None
```

and have a subclass, something like `StudentDBRecord`, that will be mapped to the database.

```
class StudentDBRecord(Student):
    def __init__(self, student):
        super(StudentDBRecord, self).__init__(student.sid, student.name,
            student.allocated_proj_ref, student.allocated_rank)

# this call remains the same
students_table = Table('studs', metadata,
    Column('sid', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String),
    Column('allocated_proj_ref', Integer, ForeignKey('projs.proj_id')),
    Column('allocated_rank', Integer)
)

# this changes
mapper(StudentDBRecord, students_table, properties={'proj' : relation(Project)})
```

Now you would implement your optimization algorithm using instances of `Student`, which are unmapped - so as the attributes of the `Student` objects change, nothing happens to the database. This means you can safely use `copy` or `deepcopy` as needed. When you're all done, you can change the `Student` instances to `StudentDBRecord` instances, something like

```
students = ...dict with best solution...
student_records = [StudentDBRecord(s) for s in students.itervalues()]
session.commit()
```

This will create mapped objects corresponding to all your students in their optimal state and commit them to the database.

*EDIT 2*: So maybe that doesn't work. A quick fix would be to copy the `Student` constructor into `StudentDBRecord` and make `StudentDBRecord` extend `object` instead. That is, replace the previous definition of `StudentDBRecord` with this:

```
class StudentDBRecord(object):
    def __init__(self, student):
        self.sid = student.sid
        self.name = student.name
        self.allocated_project = student.allocated_project
        self.allocated_rank = student.allocated_rank
```

Or if you wanted to generalize it:

```
class StudentDBRecord(object):
    def __init__(self, student):
        for attr in dir(student):
            if not attr.startswith('__'):
                setattr(self, attr, getattr(student, attr))
```

This latter definition will copy over all non-special properties of the `Student` to the `StudentDBRecord`.

Comment: @David: Just updated my question with an example of one of the Classes. "...if you don't want the original database record to change when you update the copy" - that's what I'm looking for. Could you describe what exactly you mean by "`you can implement the copy operation by creating a new instance of the same class and copying over the values`"? Do I have sort of define a "localised" version of `__deepcopy__()` for my SQLA-mapped class? I think I get what you mean by the last line but could you kindly clarify it a bit more concretely? Perhaps an example?

Comment: What I meant was something like `def __deepcopy__(self, memo): return Student(deepcopy(self.sid, memo), deepcopy(self.name, memo), deepcopy(self.allocated_project, memo), deepcopy(self.allocated_rank, memo))` (note that you will no longer be able to use `sid` as a primary key if you do this).

Comment: @David: Have updated the question. The `__deepcopy__()` method is a bit too much for me since I'm wrapping up stuff, however, I've sort of followed your "separate class-same fields-unmapped" solution. Could you explain what you mean by subclass in this case?

Comment: @David: Can SQLA deal with inheritance?

Comment: @Az: Sure, there's even a section in the documentation about how to map multiple classes that are related in a common hierarchy. So I don't expect that it would have any trouble doing this, where the superclass is unmapped and the subclass is. But I haven't actually tested the code so I couldn't tell you for sure.

Comment: @David: Okidokey, I'll give it a try and let you know if it works (and if so, then finally get that green tickmark going) :)

Comment: @David: Oh no... I got an `Error`.

Comment: @David: Tried the generalised `StudentDBRecord`. Mapped that with SQLA, did `student_records = [StudentDBRecord(s) for s in best_node[1].itervalues()]` (where `best_node[1]` is the optimal `students` dictionary) followed by `session.commit()`. Then I tried to print the contents of `StudentDBRecord` and got (drumroll)... a `0`.

Comment: @Az: Weird, even if it didn't work you shouldn't just be getting `0` when you print it. Try adding a `__str__` method to `StudentDBRecord`.

Comment: @David: I'm using a combination of techniques to get `deepcopy` and SQLA ORM'ing working, so many thanks for the different ideas that you've explored in your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option, but I'm not sure it's applicable to your problem:

1. Retrieve objects from database along with all needed relations. You can either pass `lazy='joined'` or `lazy='subquery'` to relations, or call `options(eagerload(relation_property)` method of query, or just access required properties to trigger their load.
2. Expunge object from session. Lazy loading of object properties won't be supported from this point.
3. Now you can safely modify object.
4. When you need to update the object in the database you have to merge it back into session and commit.

**Update**: Here is prove of concept code sample:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relation, eagerload

metadata  = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata, name='Base')

class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'students'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    project_id = Column(ForeignKey(Project.id))
    project = relation(Project,
                       cascade='save-update, expunge, merge',
                       lazy='joined')

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

proj = Project(name='a')
stud = Student(project=proj)
session.add(stud)
session.commit()
session.expunge_all()
assert session.query(Project.name).all()==[('a',)]

stud = session.query(Student).first()
# Use options() method if you didn't specify lazy for relations:
#stud = session.query(Student).options(eagerload(Student.project)).first()
session.expunge(stud)

assert stud not in session
assert stud.project not in session

stud.project.name = 'b'
session.commit() # Stores nothing
assert session.query(Project.name).all()==[('a',)]

stud = session.merge(stud)
session.commit()
assert session.query(Project.name).all()==[('b',)]
```

Comment: I'm not very experienced with SQLA... would it be possible to give me a more specific example of this method?

Comment: I've got it working now with a combination of a mapped and an unmapped class. Not as elegant slightly easier to keep track of for me. However, I endeavour to give your solution a go (and keep it for reference) in the future. Thanks for the help :)